# Class functions + Threading

Tags: c++, multithreading, class

I already searched the web, but I found nothing about it.

I know that assembled source-code (e.g. c++) is not copied to virtual memory when started. In fact when I create a new class instance, a new instance of variables are created in memory, but the classes program code still remains in read-only memory (e.g. harddrive or flash) so there is only ONE program code for X classes (?).

Now I take these classes and put them in 2 new threads. So if I start both threads in asynchonous mode at the same time and start a function declared in that class, does that mean that I call the SAME function at the same time?

Example:

```
class test
{
   int _test()
   {
      int temp = 0;
      temp += 1; // thread 2 would call this ..
      temp = temp / 2; // .. while thread 1 is already here which means temp+=1 was called twice - (0+1+1)/2 = 1 !!
   }
};

int main()
{
   test test1;
   test test2;

   new_async_thread(test1._test());
   new_async_thread(test2._test());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **code** for the function will be same. But the *arguments* and the *local variables* declared will be placed in separate stack space. So the **SAME** code will operate on **Different** data.

Comment: Perfect, I did not know that _test_ would allocate its own _temp_ variable. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

No, each thread has its own stack, and `temp` is a stack-allocated variable so it will not be shared between the two threads.  Likewise the two threads will have two separate return values from the same function, though the *instructions* executed in the function do the same thing--just to different instances of the variable `temp`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have a basic misunderstanding.

Automatic local variables are local to, or belong to, a function's *invocation*. Each variable has its own storage - which isn't "inside the function" - all they share is a name in the source code.
So each function invocation has its own completely independent local variables.
This makes the function *reentrant*, which means that a function can be invoked in the middle of itself without affecting the result of the current invocation.
Reentrancy enables both multithreading and recursion.

So you *are* calling the same function, but each function computes its own `temp` value (which is 0).